# Rails if condition with params not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameters, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a condition with params. In my Rails application I have facilities in several cities. I have a map (using Mapbox) for each city showing all the facilities in that city. I would also like to have a map for the whole world (including markers), but don’t seem to get the params right - the world map doesn’t work **or** the city map includes the whole world depending on the params I choose. When I investigate, I have (naturally) on the city map page the city_id as a param (`<ActionController::Parameters {"search"=><ActionController::Parameters {"city_id"=>"2"} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"facilities", "action"=>"maps"} permitted: false>`). On the whole world map page the params are: `<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"facilities", "action"=>"maps", "format"=>"#<Facility::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fe5f6e32e00>"} permitted: false>`.

The code in the facilities controller:

```
  def maps   // THE COMMENTED IF-ELSE WORKS FOR CITY MAP, WORLD DOESN'T WORK
    # if "city_id".present?
    #     @facilities = Facility.joins(:city).where(city_id: params[:search][:city_id])
    #    @facilities = @facilities.joins(:category).where("categories.id = ?", params[:search][:category_id]) if params[:search][:category_id].present?
    # else
    #   @facilities = Facility.all
    # end
    // THE BELOW PART WORKS FOR WORLD MAP, CITY MAP GIVES WORLD MAP AS WELL
    if @city.blank?
      @facilities = Facility.all
    else
      @facilities = Facility.joins(:city).where(city_id: params[:search][:city_id])
      @facilities = @facilities.joins(:category).where("categories.id = ?", params[:search][:category_id]) if params[:search][:category_id].present?
    end
    @markers = []
    @facilities.each do |facility|
      unless facility.address.blank?
      map_info = render_to_string(partial: "/facilities/map_box", locals: { facility: facility })
      @markers << {
        lat: facility.latitude,
        lng: facility.longitude,
        image_url: helpers.asset_url('placemarker.png'),
        infoWindow: { content: map_info }
      }
      end
    end
    authorize :facility, :map?   end
```

`If @city == nil` or `@city.blank?` is the only way I get the world map working, with all the other options I’ve tried (`if "city_id".blank?, unless "city_id".present?, if "city_id" == ""`…) I get the error “undefined method `[]` for nil:NilClass” and the line `@facilities = Facility.joins(:city).where(city_id: params[:search][:city_id])` is highlighted. So it seems that the first option in the if-else is ignored, and I really don’t understand why - the city page accepts only city_id and the world page accepts only @city. I have tried all kind of combinations with && and || and changed the order of the two options but still I always get only one of them working. Ive

I would be really happy for any suggestions! If some vital information is missing, I'll be happy to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all possible conditions with params I finally have it working with `if url.include?('city_id')`. Not the cleanest way, but at least it's displaying what I want. If someone else has an idea how to do it with params, I would still be happy to find out!